# Data Driven testing with Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, data-driven-tests

I am new to junit concept.

Can anyone explain to me clearly what the Data Driven concept is?

And another other question would be if we can write two `RunWith`-annotated methods in one junit class.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
...
```

and

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
...
```

Comment: This might help you [ JUnit tutorial ] (http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29139/

Explains data driven concept in detail. Mainly it invlolves in creating different sets of data to test the code in short. Mainly used to write automated test cases where a certain piece of code is always run through different types of test data and tested for desired output.

And for the second question I don't think multiple @Runwith method makes sense, as it is a directive for junit to load proper runner to execute testcases instead of default runner built into the Junit. I haven't tried it also. Hope this offers some answer to your question.

Comment: i have 3 datapoints of string array and 2 datapoints of integer array.

@Theory
public void xxx(String[] result ,Integer[] checkdt )

when running this testcases it is taking 3 datapoints of string array,but i want to use only 2 datapoints of String array .how can i use only 2 datapoints ?

Comment: can your function which you are testing through unit tests returns valid answer with only ywo string datapaoints?